# RAID controller write back performance

Tags: raid

What kind of performance benefit write back on a RAID controller gives?

To be more specific, the setup is 2 SSDs in RAID 1. The workload is mainly random write.

Given the above, what kind of performance increase can I expect using write back vs write through on a RAID card with 1GB RAM?

More information:

**OS**: Cent OS 6.5
**CPU**: Intel Xeon E3-1240v2
**SSD**: Intel S3500 160GB
**RAID controller**: MegaRAID SAS 9271-8i

Comment: Brand of server, make/model of RAID controller, brand/model of SSD... Some basic information that will make this a better question and help us provide good answers.

Comment: I assume you know that write operations are no faster on RAID-1 than to a single disk (can even be slower for rotating media) - and that your not getting better reliability than a single disk - the expected failure mode for SSDs is write-wear that both the disks will expire at the same time unless you buy three and swap one out half way through its duty cycle.

Comment: I know write operations are a bit slower depending on the controller, but I believed by buying 2 SSDs and RAID 1 them I get better reliability. I see your point regarding write-wear, but I believe this covers me in case of *unexpected* failures. This is provided by a hosting company, so I have no way to know how much data were written on an SSD.

Answer (score 1):

For that specific hardware combination, the controller cache may not provide much help.

- The Intel SSDs you're using provide power-loss protection, so the BBWC's function may be redundant. I doubt you'd see a difference with and without cache with *those* SSDs.
- The write IOPs capacity of those SSDs should absorb a random write workload well.

The best performance enhancement you can make here is to leverage your LSI controller's [**FastPath** functionality](http://www.lsi.com/products/raid-controllers/pages/megaraid-fastpath-software.aspx). This optimizes the data path for SSDs instead of the algorithms tuned for rotational media.

Comment: When you say not much performance difference, I understand it's very hard to estimate performance, but can you be a bit more specific, eg up to 20% or so, if possible please? Also, this is provided by a hosting company and the don't provide FastPath.

Comment: On controllers of that generation, I [don't enable battery or flash-backed caching on volumes comprised of SSDs](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/kb/docDisplay/?sp4ts.oid=3902574&spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay&spf_p.prp_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-navigationalState%3DdocId%253Demr_na-c02963968-2%257CdocLocale%253D%257CcalledBy%253D&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken). So I can't tell you how much *your* application will benefit or not from that configuration. I **can** tell you that it's moot because FastPath is on a different order of performance increase.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Above you write "BBWC's function may be redundant.". If I use write back and don't use BBU, Will I be safe, given the SSDs provide power loss failure?